# Remove row in Dataframe if Contains Question Marks Python 3

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am a newbie here so please forgive for any mistakes. I am trying to work on Hdfc Bank dataset. I am finding it hard to remove the question marks in the dataset.
I am facing difficult to analysis on this dataset. I am trying please help me

I am trying on [this code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lGV4lFxKtDUHJoTofd87o3dqbWZ5kFOZ) but it gets but  showing errors, how could  i solve this? please help me.

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . try to improve the question format

Answer (score 0):

I cannot run your notebook because I don't have access to the data, but it looks like your columns are strings (only `bad_flag` shows output when you run `describe()`). You have two options:

1) Replace the `?` in the columns by `np.nan`. For example, you could try this in one column (and, if it works, apply it to the whole dataframe):

```
ag_train['V3_replaced'] = ag_train.V3.replace('?', np.nan)
```

2) Convert the columns to numeric, and coerce the '?' to `np.nan`, like this:

```
ag_train['V3_converted'] = pd.to_numeric(ag_train.V3, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Thank you mirosa  , after converting the columns to numeric what should I do please help me. I trying very hard to analysis on this dataset.

Comment: I'm a little confused. The conversion should have replaced the '?' in your columns with NaNs, so that now you have numeric columns that you can use for your analysis. I thought that's what your question was about. Am I missing something?

Comment: sorry about my poor Grammarly mistakes.I am saying  after  converting numeric values,  what should   I do  please give suggestions  to me .

Comment: I do please help me, I am feeling very difficult to build a model for this data set.

Comment: "What should I do?" is not really a question I (or anyone) can help you with here on SO. You should take a look at the resources here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and ask pointed and clear questions as you advance so that people can help you. If you need more general help about how to do data analysis, build models, etc., you should probably look elsewhere. There's plenty of free resources online that will guide you through doing basic data analysis and model building.